# If Then copy cell to new destination

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn VBA, but stuck on a piece of code

I have a data set (containing headers) that I need to loop through all rows containing data in column 5, If the value is 250 or greater, then copy this cell and the cell in column 1 to a new worksheet say column A and B.

My current code seems to paste every cell, not just the ones where the value is 250 or greater

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    'Check if DSLP is old
      If Cells(i, 1).Value >= 250 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=RI.Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(i, 5).Copy Destination:=RI.Cells(i, 2)
      End If 'Account dslp is old
Next i
```

Comment: You are performing your check on column A, but your question implies that you should be checking column E

Comment: change `If Cells(i, 1).Value >= 250 Then` to `If Cells(i, 5).Value >= 250 Then`

Comment: Perfect, I am such an idiot to miss that.  Is there a way to copy to a new destination but without the blanks, e.g. if a code copies a cell in row 10 and on row on the first sheet and place the values on a new worksheet, but without the 9 spaces in between?

Comment: Sure that can be done - generally you would open a new question for asking a different question, but I'll oblige: Just add a variable `insertRow`, set it equal to 1 outside the for loop, use it inside the `If` block: `Destination:=RI.Cells(insertRow, 1)` and increment it at the end of the If block `insertRow = insertRow + 1`